# Dynamic arguments to expand.grid

Tags: r, combinations

I am using `expand.grid` to generate all of the pairs of the elements of a vector, such as:

```
v <- 1:3
expand.grid(v,v)
```

Which gives:

```
  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2
5    2    2
6    3    2
7    1    3
8    2    3
9    3    3
```

Now, say I want the same thing but with triplets I use

```
expand.grid(v,v,v)
```

How would I go about generalizing this to n-tuples so that I can use `new.expand.grid(v,5)` and have the result of `expand.grid(v,v,v,v,v)`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`expand.grid` can take a `list` as its input, so what about `replicate`?

```
expand.grid(replicate(3, v, simplify=FALSE))
```

---

For fun, as a function (though I know you would know how to do this):

```
new.expand.grid <- function(input, reps) {
  expand.grid(replicate(reps, input, simplify = FALSE))
}

new.expand.grid(c(1, 2), 4)
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1     1    1    1    1
# 2     2    1    1    1
# 3     1    2    1    1
# 4     2    2    1    1
# 5     1    1    2    1
# 6     2    1    2    1
# 7     1    2    2    1
# 8     2    2    2    1
# 9     1    1    1    2
# 10    2    1    1    2
# 11    1    2    1    2
# 12    2    2    1    2
# 13    1    1    2    2
# 14    2    1    2    2
# 15    1    2    2    2
# 16    2    2    2    2
```

Comment: Great! I did not really think about doing it this way!

Answer (score 6):

`do.call` is the standard way of passing a dynamic set of arguments to a function:

```
new.expand.grid <- function(vec,nrep) do.call(expand.grid,rep(list(vec),nrep))
```

Example: `new.expand.grid(letters[1:2],4)`

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1     a    a    a    a
2     b    a    a    a
3     a    b    a    a
4     b    b    a    a
5     a    a    b    a
6     b    a    b    a
7     a    b    b    a
8     b    b    b    a
9     a    a    a    b
10    b    a    a    b
11    a    b    a    b
12    b    b    a    b
13    a    a    b    b
14    b    a    b    b
15    a    b    b    b
16    b    b    b    b
```

Comment: Point taken about `do.call`, but I think it is overkill in this case. `expand.grid(rep(list(v), 4))` would be sufficient. I would guess that benchmarking just the `rep` vs `replicate` part of our answers, one would find the `rep` approach to be faster.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yeah, I was just thinking about how to construct the exact call the OP mentioned, instead of, you know, giving the most useful answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest (and shortest) solution is the following:

```
expand.grid(rep(list(1:3), 2)) 
  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    1    2
5    2    2
6    3    2
7    1    3
8    2    3
9    3    3
```